# Stock Amchart Serial with Value-Based Data rather than Date-Based?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am looking to build a chart with all the interactive functionality of the [Amchart Date-Based Data chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/) however with an x-axis that is Value-based (an incremental integer). Is there a simple way to specify the data type of the x-axis or is this effectively impossible and I should instead consider an XY-type chart?

Ideally I would load the XY values from a CSV file to populate the XY axes. I would like to supply the chart from this function:

```
function loadChartData() {
    var chartData = [];
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        // change string (from CSV) into number format
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.Rank = +d.Rank;
            d["Score"] = +d["Score"];
          chartData.push({
                Rank: d.Rank,
                Score: d["Score"]
            });
            //console.log(d);
        });
    return chartData;
}
```

Where Rank is the X-axis incremental integer and Y-axis a Double-type value.

Thank you!

Comment: AmCharts' stock charts only support a date-based category axis so a numeric x axis isn't possible. XY is more appropriate if you need numeric x and y axes.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this, xorspark, I imagined as much.